# 3D city build in Blender

Tags: 3d-printing, photorealism

I would like to print my city with a 3D printer, but for this I need a model. I found a lot of information via YouTube (and other sources), but I don't think Belgium puts good 3D data online (BTW we do not have the 3D function on Google Maps in Belgium, that's quite strange). I don't get decent houses through all the techniques, the houses are all the same size and have no roofs. Are there techniques that can help me get perfect houses?

But the LIDAR data is online (that's very cool), so I can make houses with the correct height and roofs. But when I process this data I do not get nice houses, as you can see in the attachment, the corners are completely round, so it doesn't seem realistic at all. This is probably because the LIDAR data was taken with an airplane (so only the roofs and streets were photographed, not the walls), but is there a way to make this more realistic?

Thanks for the responses.

[image]

Comment: [MeshLab](https://www.meshlab.net/) may be a more adequate tool for what you are looking to achieve

Comment: I feel like this is just barely relevant to blender, and more about how to get an accurate 3-D model of your city.

Answer (score 0):

The process described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NW_djQS_N8U) is a bit complicated, but I think the results are worth it.
It uses an addon called Blender-OSM, which automates a lot of the buildings for you, but you do have to sign up for a free account with Mapbox. (to get access the map data)